# Java - sending packets via UDP

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp

In my android app, I am sending messages via UDP. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997459/send-and-receive-serialize-object-on-udp-in-java) and [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip40.html?page=2).
However, I am not able to send the initial packet from the client to the server. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong in my code below:

```
class serverCommunicationThread implements Runnable 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        try {
            serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(STATICPORT);
            ServerReceiveMessageThread rcvMsgThread = new ServerReceiveMessageThread(serverSocket);
            new Thread(rcvMsgThread).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

This is the ServerReceiveMessageThread class:

```
class ServerReceiveMessageThread implements Runnable
{
    DatagramSocket clientSocket;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[108];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

    ServerReceiveMessageThread(DatagramSocket clientSocket)
    {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        int counter = 0;
        MsgStruct recvMsgStruct = null;

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baosServer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            serializeServer = new ObjectOutputStream(baosServer);

            clientSocket.receive(packet);
            ByteArrayInputStream baosRecv = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
            deserializeServer = new ObjectInputStream(baosRecv);

            while(true)
            {
                try {
                    recvMsgStruct = (MsgStruct) deserializeServer.readObject();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                boolean retVal = serverSendMessage(clientSocket, recvMsgStruct, baosServer.toByteArray());
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
}
```

The serverSendMessage method:

```
public boolean serverSendMessage(DatagramSocket clientSocket, MsgStruct msgStruct, byte[] buf)
{
        MsgStruct recvMsgStruct = new MsgStruct();
        recvMsgStruct.pingPong = true;
        recvMsgStruct.msgId = msgStruct.msgId;
        recvMsgStruct.bufferMsg = msgStruct.bufferMsg;

        try {
            serializeServer.writeObject(recvMsgStruct);
            serializeServer.flush();
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, InetAddress.getByName(mobileIP), STATICPORT);
            clientSocket.send(packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
}
```

The code for the client send/receive is similar to that of the server. I get a NullPointerException here.

```
serializeClient.writeObject(mobileSendMsgStruct);
```

---

```
public boolean mobileSendMessage(int msgId)
{
    MsgStruct mobileSendMsgStruct = new MsgStruct();
    mobileSendMsgStruct.bufferMsg = new byte[100];

        mobileSendMsgStruct.pingPong = false;
        mobileSendMsgStruct.msgId = msgId;
        rand.nextBytes(mobileSendMsgStruct.bufferMsg);
        try {
            sendTime = System.nanoTime();
            serializeClient.writeObject(mobileSendMsgStruct); /*I get a NullPointerException here*/
            serializeClient.flush();
            byte[] sendBuf = baosSend.toByteArray();
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(sendBuf, sendBuf.length, InetAddress.getByName(staticIP), STATICPORT);
            mobileSocket.send(packet);
            outPing.write(Long.toString(sendTime) + ", " + String.valueOf(mobileSendMsgStruct.msgId) + ", " + String.valueOf(mobileSendMsgStruct.bufferMsg) + " | ");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } 
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize serializeClient?

Comment: I was initializing it in a thread similar to ServerReceiveMessageThread. The problem was that the initialization did not get over while the client started sending data. I found out that problem and am able to send data from client. But now, the server is blocking at this line -       recvMsgStruct = (MsgStruct) deserializeServer.readObject();

Comment: See what deserializeServer.available() returns.  It should tell you how many btyes are available without blocking.  I would expect that the server would wait for data, so perhaps your packets aren't getting across (in which case you might look into a packet capture (wireshark) to debug the network and return to java land once you're sure it's coming across.